# what is azuredevops pools maintenance job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Is AzureDevops pools maintenance job can be restricted to specific path ?

What are all directories it willl be deleting or cleaning up. If we have some cofig settings settled in any files, will this cleanup will affect them ?

Answer (score 2):

With Maintenance jobs you can configure agent pools to periodically clean up stale working directories and repositories.This means that they will clean up the working directories for your agents based on the settings that you define.

The working directories are the folders with numbers inside `C:\agent\work`. Every number is a separate pipeline run on which the source code is downloaded, the artifacts are stored etc. Maintenance jobs will empty these directories that are not used for a specific period of time.

Every time the same pipeline runs on the same agent, it will use the same working directory and it will override the previous files.

Regarding the config files, I believe that you do not set them directly in the working directories folders. If not, then it will not affect your settings.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser